# Switch off autocorrect in libreoffice calc for specific document, column, cell

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, autocorrect

There is a [way](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Turning_Off_AutoCorrect) to completely turn off autocorrect in libreoffice calc. However, I would prefer turn off autocorrect in less scale: document, worksheet, column/row, cell. How it can be obtained?

Comment: I believe this is actually a feature request on the bugzilla pages for LibreOffice and OpenOffice.  Currently autocorrect is absolutely global and there is no option for smaller scale customization.