# How to undo autocorrect in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, undo, autocorrect

I would like to prevent libreoffice calc to make autocorrecion in some cases in some cell. For example, sometimes libreoffice decides that some text I enter is a hyperlink and it formats the cell as a hyperlink. How I can undo this autoformatting case? (When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, calc removes my entered text). I do not need completely turn off autocorrection in libreoffice calc.

Comment: Hi Loom, it appears that you have two very similar questions which have slightly different scopes and information. Perhaps you could merge the two and delete one or the other? (cf http://superuser.com/questions/936904/switch-off-autocorrect-in-libreoffice-calc-for-specific-document-column-cell)

Comment: Hi @bertieb. Yes, answers for both questions are for solving one problem. However, answers for both questions are differ, so I couldn't select right  answer for the suggested merged question

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, neither of these questions have answers at time of writing- is there another set of questions you are referring to?

Comment: It's looks my English obstructs my attempts to explain) I meant, that if each of my questions would have an answer, then these answers would differ. I would like to know answers for both questions. If I merged my questions I could lose one of the answers.

Comment: I understand now. In my opinion, the questions are similar enough that you could ask both in one post (as two bullet points), but you are entitled to your opinion as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's currently no way of doing this cleanly, here's a workaround:

Assuming you have entered e.g. `http://test.com` into a cell, and it got auto-formatted as a hyperlink.

1. Click the cell so that it becomes active (make sure it has indeed become active, because clicking the hyperlink itself will do nothing)
2. Select the text in the formula bar
3. Cut it
4. Press Enter (thus getting empty cell)
5. Press Up (or click the cell)
6. Press Ctrl+Shift+V to call Paste Special
7. In the Paste Special dialog which appears click OK, making sure "Unformatted text" is selected in the list

Now you should have the link pasted without any special formatting.